# Handle UnknownHostException properly in RabbitMQ, preventing auto recovery

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I have written a Spring Application that is implementing RabbitMQ manually with the RabbitMQ Client API.

The way the Connection Factory and Connection are set are similar to the tutorial:

```
public class Recv {
  private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

  public static void main(String[] argv)
      throws java.io.IOException,
             java.lang.InterruptedException {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("122.34.1.1");
    factory.setPort(5672);
    factory.setUsername("user");
    factory.setPassword("password")
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
    ...
    }
}
```

The connection works correct.  However, if I turn off my host server, my application seems to stuck in some sort of loop where it tries to auto recover by keep pinging the turned-off host.

Because of this, my console get filled with tons of stacktraces that say "UnknownHostException".  The exact location according to stacktraces is the line:

```
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
```

I have tried to put a try-catch block around this line, but that doesn't seem to work at all.

If the traditional try-catch block can't handle the exception coming from the connection, what is the proper way to catch the exception and stop the auto-recovery from creating this loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your Rabbit like this (on both ends):

```
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        final CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(server);
        connectionFactory.setUsername("user");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("pass");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

The port should be set by default. If not, it will show on startup and you can change it. The Queue should be declared and set by the consumer (host or whatever you call it).
And put a @EnableRabbit annotation on your configuration class if you haven't.

Consumer declares a Queue:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
@Component
public class RabbitListener {

    @Bean
        public Queue getQueue() {
            return new Queue("myQueue");
        }

        @RabbitHandler
        public void getElementFromMyQueue(@Payload Object object) {

            // handle object as you want
    }
}
```

After that just @Autowire the RabbitTemplate on the sender and you should be good to go. The queue should remain idle but 'active', even when the host is down

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But for my application, I am trying to start every component including the connection manually.  Using the bean method would mean that all the resources are being established at the the start of the application.  Do you know if there is a proper way I can apply to connection to make sure the exception and the auto-recovery are being handled properly?

Comment: Well, spring boot is all about convention over configuration, after all. So I wouldn't be trying to reinvent the wheel. However, you can also
extend the exception and throw it. Spring has some cool annotations for writing exception handler methods. And over there you can do close it manually or do whatever it suits your requirements.